# No FileSystem for scheme "az" error when trying to read csv from ADLS Gen2 using PySpark

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-synapse

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.pandas as ps
```

I am trying to use the pyspark pandas api to compare performance between two similar scripts (one using pandas and one using pyspark through the pandas interface). However, I have trouble importing my data in pyspark from our ADLS Gen 2 storage.

When I run the following code it works as expected:

```
df_pandas = pd.read_csv(f"az://container/path/to/file.csv",sep=';', dtype=str)
```

However when I run the same using the pyspark pandas api:

```
df_spark = ps.read_csv(f"az://container/path/to/file.csv",sep=';', dtype=str)
```

However, when I run this the following error gets thrown:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1840.load.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "az"
```

I have looked online and found others with similar problems using AWS but I'm not sure how to solve it for Azure. I tried replacing `az` with `abfs` but I then get the error:

```
An error occurred while calling o1852.load.
: abfs://container/path/to/file.csv has invalid authority.
```

I'm running these from Azure Synapse notebooks btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce same in environment.I got this output.

> **Reading csv files from ADLS Gen2.**

**Code:**

```
import pandas 
df = pandas.read_csv('abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<file_path>', storage_options = {'account_key' : 'account_key_value'})
```

**Output:**

[image]

For more information refer this [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool#readwrite-data-using-secondary-adls-account) and [link2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qTEGAzEYhw&t=290s).

Comment: Thanks, I had to add '<container_name>@<storage_account_name>......' instead of just container_name.